# Setting numpy array to slice without any in-place operations

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, sparse-matrix, in-place

How can I do this operation efficiently without any inplace operations?

```
n_id = np.random.choice(np.arange(2708), size=100)
z = np.random.rand(100, 64)
z_sparse = np.zeros((2708,64))
z_sparse[n_id[:100]] = z
```

Essentially I want the n_id rows of z_sparse to contain z's rows, but I can't do any inplace operations because my end goal is to use this in a pytorch problem.

One though would be to create zero rows within z precisely so that the rows of z end up in the positions n_id, but not sure how this would work efficiently.

Essentially row 1 of `z` should be placed at row `n_id[0]` of `z_sparse`, then row 2 of `z` should be at row `n_id[1]` of `z_sparse`, and so on...

Here's the PyTorch error jic you are curious:
`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation`

Comment: I'm pretty sure pytorch supports in-place operations.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica not when it's in your computation graph - it breaks the graph

Comment: is `n_id` a fixed tensor?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes.

Comment: Just curious, do you need that in your graph, or can you put all of that inside `with torch.no_grad():`

Comment: @QuangHoang I need `z` in my graph. The issue is the index of `z`. I need to index `z` with `n_id` but `z` is only len 100 and n_id can be up to 2708

Comment: is passing a copy and changing that not an option?

Comment: @Ehsan I'd need to see the code to be sure.

Comment: That requires you to provide the minimal code for this. Would that be possible for you? I am not sure of the processes you do in your graph.

Comment: @Ehsan if you can do the operation above in numpy I can translate it to torch. Essentially row 1 of `z` should be placed at row `n_id[0]` of `z_sparse`, then row 2 of `z` should be at row `n_id[1]` of `z_sparse`, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n_id` is a fixed index array, you can get `z_sparse` as a matrix multiplication:

```
# N, n, m = 2078,100, 64
row_mat = (n_id[:n] == np.arange(N)[:,None])

# for pytorch tensor
# row_mat = Tensor(n_id[:n] == np.arange(N)[:,None])

z_sparse =  row_mat @ z
```

Since `row_mat` is a constant array (tensor), your graph should work just fine.

Comment: very creative answer

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the `[:, None]` slicing does?

Comment: @Guimoute That's called [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). and somewhat equivalent with `.reshape(-1,1)`.